# How do I create text file with 2 variable in it?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that saves a name and score. Currently it stores the name and score in 2 different files. I display them as high scores with 2 listboxes.

I know that it is possible to do something along the lines of ('score|name') and then call it back and split it with the pipe. I want to be able to save a number and name in that sort of format and then call it back in a listbox and have the largest number and the corresponding name show in a label as "Highscore held by {name} with {number}!"

Alternatively, as the project has 3 variables: type, mode and difficulty, along with the name and score. Would it be possible to save it as ('type|mode|diff|score|name') and then check for the correct mode etc. for each page on the high scores page.

I am not wording this too well, so I can upload the entire code to GitHub if need be. I have done this in a very round-about way.

I have posted the relevent code below.

```
Sub AA1()
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "calculator\addition\attack\1.txt")
    Dim aryText(0) As String
    aryText(0) = mdiparent1.overall
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
    objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(0))
    objWriter.Close()
    MsgBox("Score and Name Saved")
End Sub
```

\\

```
Sub AAN1()
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "calculator\addition\attack\name\1.txt")
    Dim aryText(0) As String
    aryText(0) = mdiparent1.username
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
    objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(0))
    objWriter.Close()
    'MsgBox("Score and Name Saved")
End Sub
```

\\

```
Sub file_createAA()
    Dim filepath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "calculator\addition\attack\1.txt")
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

\\

```
Sub file_createAAN()
    Dim filepath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "calculator\addition\attack\name\1.txt")
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what you mean two variable?is it two column of value with N row of record?

Comment: the two variables are the name of who made the score and the score that was created

Answer (score 0):

you can try this *(VB.net code now)*

```
    Dim name As List(Of String)
    Dim score As List(Of Integer)
    Dim delimiter As String = "@@@"
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)

    For i As Integer = 0 To name.Count() Step 1
        objWriter.WriteLine(name(i) + delimiter + score(i).ToString())
    Next

    objWriter.Close()
```

Comment: this is precisely what i need, but it is in c#, and i'm using vb.net